# jQuery Dialog + Disable

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I have jQuery dialog window, upon some operations I have a blockUI plugin which I load.

The problem I'm facing is that I'm still able to perform operations when the ajax operation is performing, even though AJAX image is still showing.

The JSP page on the other hand is blocked until the operation is done, how do I block the dialog window?

There is also another possibility, I could have 2 dialog windows open and both need to be blocked until the loading is done.

How do i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If "block" means, avoid user inputs while something is going on, you can just "display" a div as overlay which has **100%** width & height. Like

css

```
div.loader 
{
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     background: transparent url(../my_animated_loader.gif) no-repeat center center;
     z-index: 1001;
}
```

If you want to "block" user inputs, just display that div on top of your dialog.